# выделение области четырёхмерного массива

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Мне нужно выделить область четырёхмерного массива , чтобы дальше работать c этой областью

```
prepare_weights_inp2(model):
   weights=model.get_weights()
   _weights_=[]
   shape=[0,0,0,0]
    for weight in weights:
       ui=list(copy.copy(weight.shape))
       while len(ui) < 4:
          ui.append(0)
       _weights_.append(ui)
       for ind , dim in enumerate(ui):
          if shape[ind] < dim:
             shape[ind]=dim
    mask=np.zeros(shape)
    ls=[0,0,0,0]
    q1=lambda sc : np.indices(range(ls[sc],_shape_[sc]))
    dynamic_x=_weights_[0][0]
    for _shape_ in _weights_:
        _shape_[0]=dynamic_x
        q,w,e,r=q1(0),q1(1),q1(2),q1(3)
        mask[q,w,e,r]=weights
        dynamic_x+=weight.shape[0]
        ls=[o+1 for o in copy.copy(_shape_)]
    return mask
```

weights=model.get_weights() возвращает объект list() , заполненный n-мерными (до 4 ) np.array 
выдаётся ошибка :

```
mask[q,w,e,r]=weights
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Макет задачи на 2D array

```
    arr=np.zeros([10,20])
arr[:3][:2]=np.ones([2,1])
```

mask - это просто "пустое полотно"

пример дынных

```
from keras.layers import Input , Dense , Conv2D , MaxPooling2D , Flatten

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
import cv2

x=np.zeros([1,1000,580,1])
    input_image = Input(shape=(1000,580,1),name='input_image')
    conv_1 = Conv2D(2,kernel_size=(4,4),padding='valid',activation='relu',name='conv_1')(input_image)
    max_pooling_1=MaxPooling2D(4,(4,4),padding='valid',name='max_pooling_1')(conv_1)
    dense_1 = Dense(24, activation='relu',name='dense_1')(max_pooling_1)
    dense_2 = Dense(24, activation='relu',name='dense_1_2')(dense_1)
    output= Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='out')(dense_2)
    model = Model(inputs=input_image, outputs=output)
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь в ячейку с числом положить массив, вы уверены, что хотите именно этого?

Comment: я делаю переадресацию списка ячеек q,w,e,r=q1(0),q1(1),q1(2),q1(3) в mask

Comment: ну я к тому, что вот здесь mask=np.zeros(shape), вы забиваете 4х мерный массив, но тогда получается он у вас должен быть пятимерный, раз 4 индекса указывают на следующий массив, а не на конечный элемент

Comment: непонятно что и как вы хотите выделить в 4D массивах. Приведите небольшой пример входных данных и то что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: нет , тут всё правильно . Сейчас сделаю макет задачи

Comment: в концепции всё правильно*

Comment: У меня  макет задачи не компилируется `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,6) into shape (5,12)`

Comment: сейчас исправлю

Comment: чему равны `q`, `w`, `e`, `r`?

Comment: они динамически изменяются

Comment: тут у меня и ошибка , я не могу сделать переадресацию

Comment: правда я хз как её исправить

Comment: приведите ["минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример данных"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Мы не должны вытаскивать из вас по кусочкам информацию необходимую для того, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос...

Comment: честно говоря не понимаю - что мешает вам привести пример конкретных значений для `q`,`w`,`e`,`r`, которые позволят воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: как я уже сказал , они динамические . Можно взять хоть 2**10 для q,w,e,r

Comment: но , пускай будет 4,6,3,2

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78768/discussion-between-maxu-and-sahar-vkusni).